# where ev_loop declared in libev?

Tags: c, libev

I am studying libev and ev_loop is a very important component of libev. But I searched through the libev source codes and just could not found the definition of struct ev_loop.

So, how should the ev_loop look like?

```
struct ev_loop {
  /* anything here? */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 1501 of ev.c and all of ev_vars.h

```
  struct ev_loop
  {
    ev_tstamp ev_rt_now;
    #define ev_rt_now ((loop)->ev_rt_now)
    #define VAR(name,decl) decl;
      #include "ev_vars.h"
    #undef VAR
  };
```